# Microprofile running in weblogic like spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, weblogic, microprofile

Is it possible to run **eclipse Microprofile** running in **WebLogic** like **spring boot**?

Comment: You can run a spring boot application in weblogic by packaging it as a war file. (I do this frequently).

Comment: The application has been written in EJB and pure JEE standards. Moving to microprofile may be easier than spring (I would like to avoid all code changes if I can).

Comment: Two build packaging through maven - Ear deploys to Weblogic and executable Jar for micro profile.